# Creating two containers of WSO2 Apim (Active-Active Setup)

Tags: wso2-api-manager

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wso2-apim
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wso2-apim
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wso2-apim
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wso2-apim
        image: wso2/wso2am:3.2.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9443
```

Run: `kubectl apply -f wso2-apim-deployment.yaml`

Above info script from Chatgpt. Please help me if this script is accurate to deploy a container with active-active setup? I'm going to deploy a WSO2, someone could help me to check the script or any suggestion to update this. It is really appreciated. I'm using here microk8s.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here is correct, but this will not be enough to run APIM in an Active-Active manner in a K8s environment. For example, you need to add the proper configurations through the `deployment.toml` by mounting it as a configmap. You might need ingress resources to access the APIM portals without exposing them as NodePort services.

You can refer the official documentation[1] to get an idea on the configurations needed for an active-active setup. Furthermore, you can check the sample helm charts[2] for different deployment patterns of APIM to get an idea about the basic requirements and use that to write your own one for active-active scenario.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-an-active-active-deployment/

[2] - https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's really appreciated. I already visit your shared link, and already tried it on my own, since this is my firstime actually I can't execute the step properly because it's like I have to understand everything. I want a person more knowledge or experience related on this, hoping someone here could help me,. Do you have any suggestions how I can execute this or if you have time could you please provide me some videos step? If its thats okay to you. By the way thank you brother for your comment. really appreciated

Comment: You can refer to this medium article if go get further insights about this

https://medium.com/@rakhitharr/deploying-wso2-api-manager-in-kubernetes-cc31c6317c65